# How to change HttpRuntime settings (eg WaitChangeNotification) at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

It is easy to set settings in the web.config by typing them into the xml file. However, I would like set some settings at runtime.

Specifically I want to set the system.web/httpRuntime/WaitChangeNotification setting.

I've tried this, but it throws an error which says the configuration is readonly.

```
var section = HttpContext.Current.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection;
section.WaitChangeNotification = 6;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea, but this is entirely possible using reflection.

Here is a code example of injecting a Soap extension into the web services section of the app config:

```
// Turn the read only field non-readonly
WebServicesSection wss = WebServicesSection.Current;
SoapExtensionTypeElement e = new SoapExtensionTypeElement(typeof (TraceExtension), 1, PriorityGroup.High);

FieldInfo readOnlyField = typeof(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection).GetField("bReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
readOnlyField.SetValue(wss.SoapExtensionTypes, false);

// Bind to web services section of config
wss.SoapExtensionTypes.Add(e);

// Restore the original so other things don't break
MethodInfo resetMethod = typeof(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection).GetMethod("ResetModified", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
resetMethod.Invoke(wss.SoapExtensionTypes, null);

MethodInfo setReadOnlyMethod = typeof(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection).GetMethod("SetReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
setReadOnlyMethod.Invoke(wss.SoapExtensionTypes, null);
```

Obviously this is not *retrospective* so it will only affect values pulled out of the config after it's been done.

...and once again, you probably don't *want* to do this, but it is possible.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Have not tried this yet but looks like the answer I wanted. When you say it is not a good idea, what do you mean? Are you talking about the relative slowness of reflection - if so this would be fine if you were doing it only once on start up, right?

Comment: Yes. Also, there is an argument to say that the point of the app config is to put your config in it so it is not hardcoded. However, there are times when this approach is not possible / more annoying. For a production system you would probably want to put the actual config into the config file.

Comment: I know it's kinda old question. but I'm using this exactly way and now I need to move to a multi-thread env. I wished to capture the each thread SOAPs in the same thread. any of you dealt with it? any ideas?

Comment: @RoeeGavirel sorry, dont' have much experience with that in general, but we're using AppFabric, and:  builder.RegisterType<DataRecorder>().As<IDataRecorder>().SingleInstance(); and using locking inside that  class. Not really related to injecting the soap extension, but the extension uses the single instance of DataRecorder across all threads. Maybe you can do something similar~

Answer (score 1):

There is a different API to edit configuration file. In short, you can use [WebConfigurationManager](http://WebConfigurationManager) to open the config file to get [Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) object, modify it and then use one of [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134086.aspx) methods to save the file.

See [Editing ASP.NET Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7.aspx) from MSDN for more details. Also, note that modifying config file would restart your application.

Comment: Thanks. I don't actually want to update the file itself, but rather the currently in use settings.

Comment: @mike, AFAIK, there is no API for this!

Comment: If u add an answer that says there is no way, i will mark it correct!